# jQuery Msgbox from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a PHP backend that is flexible enough so it doesn't required to be re-coded to any fronted I may want to use. Part of this I'm trying to pass JSON from the backend that would then be transformed into a msgbox.

This is from my test page and Firebug keeps giving me an error saying:

```
missing : after property id
mybutton.title: mybutton.action
```

referring to the `mybutton.title` value.

This is the code i'm playing with:

```
var mybutton = new Object();
var mybutton = {'title': 'Done', 'action': function (){$(this).remove();}};
var title = mybutton.title;
var msg = "hello from the grave";

$("#SiteHolder").html(msg);             
$("#SiteHolder").dialog({ autoOpen: true, autoResize: true, width: 600, close: function(event, ui){$(this).remove();}, buttons: {
        mybutton.title: mybutton.action
      }
});
```

I also tried assigning the `mybutton.title` to an variable but it only returns the variable name and not the contents.

Please keep in mind that at some point this will be expanded to an array of buttons.

Comment: Can you make a JS-fiddle-version of this that would enable testing this first hand? Are you practically trying to create a frontend JS templating engine, that would create HTML based on the JSON it receives?

Comment: Short answer yes. The site I have is massive and I'm migrating the ui from Jquery UI to Bootstrap. In the process I wanted to have the back-end frontend independent. This would allows site admins to change interfaces and me program new interfaces without huge back-end code re-rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have object key `mybutton.title` it will not evaluate. Instead:

```
var buttons = {};
buttons[mybutton.title] = mybutton.action;

$("#SiteHolder").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    autoResize: true,
    width: 600,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
    },
    buttons: buttons
});
```

Answer (score 1):

dialog buttons are defined the following way:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: mybutton.title,
        click: mybutton.action
    }
] });
```

and please never write

```
var mybutton = new Object();
```

but

```
var mybutton = {};
```

And if you want to expand it later simply define mybuttons as an array of objects and say:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: mybuttons });
```

Answer (score 1):

One good way is to solve your bigger problem (minimize front/back-end dependencies) is to use a ready template-component, which mostly take JSON as parameters and can handle parsing the HTML very well. This also helps separate structure of the HTML from the code creating it, which IME helps maintenance in the long run.

Examples of these engines are [jQote](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/), [moustache](http://mustache.github.com/) and many others.